# Linux desktop software to create photo albums

Tags: linux, photography

I am wanting to design a photo album/photo book, in which I put together different photos, some text, etc. and this become a multi-page document that I would like to bring to a print shop (so export to PDF would be important). I very much enjoy [Canva](https://www.canva.com/create/photo-books/) which has useful tools such as dragging and dropping, easy swapping out of photos, resizing, and many good-looking templates. However I am looking for an offline, open source tool.

When I search for Linux software to do similar things, I mostly find tools that do "photo management" (tagging and tracking of files), or "photo editing" (modifying individual images). Maybe I am not using the right search terms.

Are there any available programs to create nice looking photo albums on Linux?

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular office software. LibreOffice Writer/Impress / Calligira

Comment: Here's something to think about most web based software has the idea of theme.  If you are willing to go through the effort to create a custom theme then you might be able to achieve a "nice looking photo album".

Answer (score 1):

I found [PicApport](https://www.picapport.de/en/index.php) to be quite captive in areas you mention. People call it easy to setup (without a need of a web-server), extensible, however some people say its buggy. I have not tested lately so I cannot judge.

If you would like to extend your albums also on more content (like videos), there is a [MediaGoblin](https://mediagoblin.org/) made for that. This tool is dependent on some underlying web server (like nginx + postgresql combination for example).

If you do not mind putting this solution on a locally hosted web server, then you could choose also from one of these programs:

- [Piwigo](https://www.piwigo.org/) - said to be one of the most capable software in photo gallery  creation
- [CopperMine](https://coppermine-gallery.net/)
- [ZenPhoto](https://www.zenphoto.org/news/zenphoto-gallery/)
- [Lychee](https://lychee.electerious.com/)

And a bunch of others - coming back to the **keyword** you asked for that should be: **linux web dynamic photo gallery**.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I mentiond "this become a multi-page document" I meant it should become a printed document. The goal is to create albums I can actually print, so some sort of export to PDF option will be required. From what I see here, these are all web-based galleries and not really aimed at printing them, no? I will clarify my question.

Comment: @user74934  FYI  There are plenty of virtual printers, they will show up as printer but generate a PDF file.  For example PDF Creator.   Also web browsers all have a print button.  Now if it prints out in a way you like is a whole different matter.  You might have to learn how to do a custom theme to format the output.